# Interactivity beteen WPF Applications

Tags: wpf, prism, mef, trayicon, eventaggregator

I am developing an WPF Application. The application will be installed in the network. I am using MEF with PRISM. I have created a login module and after successfully login I am publishing a loginsuccess event and based on the user roles I am adding views to regions.

Now, I want some kind of notification services. e.g. if someone logs in, logs off etc, the admin user will gets a tray balloon. I have also added notifyIconWpf for showing the application in tray and it is working.

I tried subscribing the login success event, but the event handler does not get executed when tried with two instances of the exe.

I will appreciate If anyone can guide me to right direction.

Comment: Based only on the question title - maybe you need WCF.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am not sure how the WCF will be responsible for that? I am using another library which communicates with Server perfectly.

Comment: I manage to do this by running a timer in admin UI and by fetching latest logged in users from db. But I have to send other notifications as well, So I think this will not be the right path.